# Problem with saving record keys with dots to indexeddb (dexie.js)

Tags: dexie

I'm currently working with dexie.js and I found a problem.
When I create a new record with keys that includes dots it will automaticaly convert them into tree structured object. `{"showing.text.okey": "okey"}` will be converted to `{showing: {text: {okey: "okey"}}}`. The strange part is that even if my code is the same, in some places it will work as inteded and in some places it will parse it as shown. I want to save it as it is. Is there a way to turn of automatic parse ?
[the strange part :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwfC7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting objects with dotted keys using [Table.add()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.add()) or [Table.put()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.put()) will not treat the dotted keys specifically - they will be kept as they are and not create nested objects, but [Table.update()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.update()) allows fine-grained updates of individual properties, every key passed to [Table.update()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.update()) can be a dotted key. The same goes with [Collection.modify()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()).

Comment: So there is no way to keep the keys as strings with dots when I use Table.update or Collection.modify ? My problem is that I need these unnested keys as strings and not as nested objects.

Comment: Table.update was designed to update nested properties. I don't think we have a test yet for the case when the property itself contains a dot but you can pass a callback to update and modify